# How can I keep prompt open while changing tab

Tags: javascript

I want my code to keep a prompt open when changing tabs.

This is because the information needed to input in the prompt is in another tab.

The issue I'm facing is that I can't create a loop keeping the prompt open while the answer is null, because that means the user cannot click Cancel if he wants to abandon inputting the prompt.

I have tried using the visibilitychange event, but as soon as the user leaves the tab, the rest of the code won't be executed. Same with focus, blur.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
myPrompt = prompt('Type here', '')

while (userhasnotclickedcancel || noinputsubmitted) {
      keep myPrompt open when changing tab
}
```

An ex of what I have tried:

```
let counter = 0;
myPrompt = prompt('Type here', '')

    while (counter != 1) {
                if (myPrompt == null) {
                    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
                        if (document.visibilityState == "visible" && counter == 1) {
                            return;
                        } else if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
                            myPrompt = prompt('Input text', '');
                            counter = 1;
                            console.log(myPrompt)
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Each tab in the browser is completely isolated.

Comment: @tromgy I understand, but using the loop above does trigger the prompt again.
The issue is that the code after it won't execute.

Comment: The `prompt` function is not "tab safe". You can see this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) for details. You may try to use the `<dialog>` element instead.